# ENFA in R. Run out of processing memory?

Tags: r, memory-management

OS: Windows 7; 4GB RAM; 3GB Processor speed; R 2.11.1,64bit

Hello all. I am trying to perform an Ecological Niche Factor Analysis in R, but I am facing a problem while trying to compile my .asc environmental features together in a list (the code for that:

```
maps <- as.kasc(list(cut_diststrm = bio1, cut_cos_asp = bio2, 
                 cut_dem = bio3, cut_sin_asp = bio4, 
                 cut_slope = bio5)).
```

As soon as I ask R to pool these features together, I get the following error message:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 218.5 Mb

I understand that I am asking my processor to allocate a lot of memory to perform the analysis, but has anyone faced this problem before? How to overcome this annoying problem?

Comment: This is a very common question, with answers all over Stack and I think a post in the FAQ as well. I suggest you search and read them.